# How to implement multiple select box

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have to read multiple values from a set of select boxes and to store it in an array in such a way that all the values in the array are unique.But am getting an error like this as "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" .

I already tried to console the values. The $event returning the value , i expect a boolean value (Either true or false)

```
  <ion-select  id="filter3" *ngIf="filter_type.travels"  (ionChange)="choose_type('travels',travels.id, $event)" multiple="true">
                        <ion-option id="filter3"  *ngFor="let travels of filter_type.travels " [value]="travels.id" [selected] = "false">{{travels.name}}</ion-option>
                </ion-select>
```

### Ts

```
choose_type(type: string, value: any, event: any)
   {
     console.log('Value' , value);
    let index;

    if (event.checked === true)
     {
        this.user_filter[type].push(value);

       }
 else
      {
         index = this.user_filter[type].indexOf(value);
        this.user_filter[type].splice(index, 1);
    }
   console.log('User filter app' , this.user_filter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably travel object might be undeinifed. use optional operator

```
[value]="travels?.id"
```